# ForArray not working inside newcommand

Tags: packages, foreach, loops

I try to use the `forarray` package but the output is different when used inside a custom `\newcommand`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{forarray}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\printforarray}{%
    \ForArray{;,}{*}{|}%
        {[*]\par|(*)}%
        {A,B;C,D}%
}

\printforarray

\end{document}
```

outputs

```
[*]
[*]
```

If I use the same `\ForArray` directly

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{forarray}

\begin{document}

\ForArray{;,}{*}{|}%
    {[*]\par|(*)}%
    {A,B;C,D}%

\end{document}
```

it outputs as expected

```
[(A)(B)]
[(C)(D)]
```

Why does it renders different? I need a usage inside a custom `\newcommand`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some important macros in the `forarray` package want to change the category code of some character in their argument. This cannot be done as soon as the macro and its arguments have already been absorbed as the argument to another command, in this case `\newcommand`.

The consequence is that you can't use `forarray` for this job, sorry.

*Unless* you make the “sublevel token" and the “function list separator” active at the time of the definition, reverting the category code to normal after it.

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{forarray}

\catcode`*=\active\catcode`|=\active
\newcommand{\printforarray}[1]{%
    \ForArray{;,}{*}{|}%
        {[*]\par|(*)}%
        {#1}%
}
\catcode`*=12 \catcode`|=12

\begin{document}

\printforarray{A,B;C,D}

\end{document}
```

This prints the expected

[image]

Not that I recommend it.

---

Here's a different approach with `expl3`. The macro `\forarray` takes two arguments; the first is a set of key-value options, the second is the array to process.

The available keys are

- `row-del`, for the input separator between rows (default `;`)
- `col-del`, for the input separator between columns (default `,`)
- `row-sep`, for code to insert between rows at the output stage (default empty)
- `col-sep`, for code to insert between columns at the output stage (default empty),
- `row-wrap`, for code to wrap each row with; the contents of the row is denoted by `#1` (default `#1`, that is, print the processed row)
- `entry-wrap`, for code to wrap each entry with; the entry is denoted by `#1` (default `#1`, that is, print the entry)
- `wrap` for a wrapper around the whole loop

See the examples in the code below; the last example defines a macro `\makematrix` that can receive an optional argument, so `\makematrix{1,2;3,4}` would print a `bmatrix`, but `\makematrix[p]{1,2;3,4}` would make a `pmatrix`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\forarray}{+mm}
 {
  \mountain_array:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }


\keys_define:nn { mountain/array }
 {
  row-del    .tl_set:N = \l__mountain_array_row_del_tl, % for input
  col-del    .tl_set:N = \l__mountain_array_col_del_tl, % for input
  row-sep    .tl_set:N = \l__mountain_array_row_sep_tl, % for output
  col-sep    .tl_set:N = \l__mountain_array_col_sep_tl, % for output
  row-wrap   .code:n   = \cs_set_protected:Nn \__mountain_array_row_wrap:n { #1 },
  entry-wrap .code:n   = \cs_set_protected:Nn \__mountain_array_entry_wrap:n { #1 },
  wrap       .code:n   = \cs_set_protected:Nn \__mountain_array_wrap:n { #1 },
 }

\seq_new:N \l__mountain_array_rows_seq
\seq_new:N \l__mountain_array_rows_out_seq
\seq_new:N \l__mountain_array_arow_seq
\seq_new:N \l__mountain_array_arow_out_seq
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { NV }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_use:Nn { NV }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mountain_array:nn
 {
  \keys_set:nn { mountain/array }
   {
    % start with a clean slate
    row-del={;},col-del={,},row-sep={},col-sep={},row-wrap={##1},entry-wrap={##1},wrap={##1},
    % set the chosen options
    #1
   }
  \__mountain_array_wrap:n { \__mountain_array_loop:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mountain_array_loop:nn
 {
  % begin the outer loop
  \seq_set_split:NVn \l__mountain_array_rows_seq \l__mountain_array_row_del_tl { #2 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l__mountain_array_rows_out_seq \l__mountain_array_rows_seq
   {
    \__mountain_array_row_wrap:n { \__mountain_array_row_process:n { \exp_not:n { ##1 } } }
   }
  \seq_use:NV \l__mountain_array_rows_out_seq \l__mountain_array_row_sep_tl
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mountain_array_row_process:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:NVn \l__mountain_array_onerow_seq \l__mountain_array_col_del_tl { #1 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l__mountain_array_onerow_out_seq \l__mountain_array_onerow_seq
   {
    \__mountain_array_entry_wrap:n { \exp_not:n { ##1 } }
   }
  \seq_use:NV \l__mountain_array_onerow_out_seq \l__mountain_array_col_sep_tl
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\makematrix}{O{b}m}{%
  \forarray{row-sep=\\,col-sep={&},wrap=\begin{#1matrix}##1\end{#1matrix}}{#2}
}

\begin{document}

\forarray{
  row-wrap={[#1]},
  entry-wrap=(#1),
  row-sep=\par,
}
{A,B;C,D}

\forarray{
  col-sep=+,
  row-sep=\par,
}
{A,B;C,D}

\forarray{
  col-sep=+,
  row-sep=\par,
  row-wrap={$#1$},
}
{a,b,c;d,e,f}

$\makematrix{1,2,3;4,5,6}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was looking for a way to use a custom `\newcommand` with a parameter list of variable length and loop through this list when the command runs. So this seems to be not the right way.

Comment: @Mountain You might be interested in the addition I made to my answer. If the code doesn't suit you, it's better to ask a new question with the details about your aim.